# weight bearing capacity of a reinforced concrete floor slab

Tags: structural-engineering

What is the weight bearing capacity per square yard of a 4" monolithic concrete floor slab poured with 3000 psi concrete in 50' x 50' squares, reinforced with 6" x 6" x 10" steel wire mesh, laid over 4" crushed limestone slag, with 4 mil poly vapor barrier?

Comment: Seen this question before, recently... However, have you looked on here? this is one that may give you diirection : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/1983/10902

Comment: It will be relatively low without steel rebar. Mesh is good for sidewalks.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (even if it isn't homework). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Also, the capacity is dependent on the relevant structural code in your location. Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Not a student homework question.  I'm a non-technical owner of a steel-building built in 1985 on a concrete slab with specs stated in original question.  Additional info: steel columns  25' and 50' have rebar in supporting piers.  Have googled the heck out of my question but formulas are way too technical for me.  Looking to rent some warehouse space but applicant has 3000-5000 lb totes and will be using @10K lb. forklift.  Don't want to rent space if he's going to break up my concrete floor.  Minimal hairline cracks after all these 33 year but my storage is relatively light..